# merge tables for staging

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis

Would this experimental code achieve my aim in replicating a source table as target table in a staging database?:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Source') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Source
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Target') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Target

CREATE TABLE #Source ( Id INT, Value CHAR(2) )
CREATE TABLE #Target ( Id INT, Value CHAR(2) )

INSERT  INTO #Source
        ( Id, Value ) values (1,'a'), (2,'b')    
INSERT  INTO #Target
        ( Id, Value )
        SELECT  1 ,
                'a1'

SELECT * FROM #Source
SELECT * FROM #Target

MERGE [#Target] AS Target
   USING [#Source] AS Source
     ON Target.Id = Source.Id
WHEN MATCHED AND
    (
         COALESCE(Target.Value, '') <> COALESCE(Source.Value, '')
    )
    THEN UPDATE SET
       Target.Value = Source.Value
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT (
        Id
       ,Value
      ) VALUES (
        Source.Id
       ,Source.Value
      );

SELECT * FROM #Source
SELECT * FROM #Target
```

Any improvements/criticism would be very much welcome.

Comment: Your `Coalesce()`ing is applying a function to column values. This means the comparisons cannot use any indexes. Are `NULL` values allowed in your tables? Is they aren't, then just remove the functions. If they're not, it might be best to write as a simple equality check with an extra couple of `OR`s for `NULL` checks.

Comment: P.S. this might be better asked over on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: gvee - I did they said that my code is too simplistic as it is no production code (-:

Comment: Be sure you understand the potential downsides to the [MERGE](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) statement

Comment: Thanks billinkc, what do you use to replicate a source table in a staging db?

Comment: Depends on many factors. How big is the table? Is there a problem with being lazy and truncating and reloading it? Assuming yes, then can I get away with only new data - is it append only? Assuming no, then I'm looking at a full blown [Incremental Load Pattern](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72494/) which you can see a DF picture on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531927/extract-sql-azure-federated-database-to-data-warehouse-with-ssis/20535133#20535133 I'd use hashbytes to generate a single column for change detection like this answer http://bit.ly/10jfJPo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will achieve your aim.

One more thing you can do is do Incremental/delta loads while doing MERGE. Get only records from Source table that are modified after last run. You can use the UpdateDate column as your filter column and store the date of last run in a different table every time you run your MERGE or ETL.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any tools (redgate) that help you to create these merge statements? I have a legacy db which has about 120 columns!

Comment: You can create a dynamic script to create MERGE statement by using sys.table & sys.columns system views. Check this link for reference: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Generate/88892/

Answer (score -2):

```
Below is the complete script to merge the two tables 


CREATE TABLE StudentDetails
(
StudentID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
StudentName VARCHAR(15)
)
GO
INSERT INTO StudentDetails
VALUES(1,'SMITH')
INSERT INTO StudentDetails
VALUES(2,'ALLEN')
INSERT INTO StudentDetails
VALUES(3,'JONES')
INSERT INTO StudentDetails
VALUES(4,'MARTIN')
INSERT INTO StudentDetails
VALUES(5,'JAMES')
GO
CREATE TABLE StudentTotalMarks
(
StudentID INTEGER  ,
StudentMarks INTEGER
)
GO
INSERT INTO StudentTotalMarks
VALUES(1,230)
INSERT INTO StudentTotalMarks
VALUES(2,255)
INSERT INTO StudentTotalMarks
VALUES(3,200)
GO
-- Select from Table
SELECT *
FROM StudentDetails
GO
SELECT *
FROM StudentTotalMarks
GO
-- Merge Statement
MERGE StudentTotalMarks AS stm
USING (
SELECT StudentID,StudentName FROM StudentDetails
)
 AS sd
ON stm.StudentID = sd.StudentID
WHEN MATCHED AND stm.StudentMarks > 250 THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET stm.StudentMarks = stm.StudentMarks + 25
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT(StudentID,StudentMarks)
VALUES(sd.StudentID,25);
GO
-- Select from Table
SELECT *
FROM StudentDetails
GO
SELECT *
FROM StudentTotalMarks
GO
-- Clean up
DROP TABLE StudentDetails
GO
DROP TABLE StudentTotalMarks
GO
```

Comment: i am using different tables in this example u cane user your table and check